# Accelerometer Drift?

Tags: accelerometer

I'm using an [ST Microelectronics LIS3DSH](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lis3dsh.pdf) accelerometer to detect tilt over an extended period of time.  I have the accelerometer securely mounted to a stationary object away from any vibration.  Over the course of two and a half days, I've found the readings slowly change in value. I've made sure it's not a defective accelerometer by performing this experiment multiple times using different accelerometers but the same exact manufacturer and part number.

Below are graphs of the type of drift I see over time.  You'll notice a change of about 0.006G on X, 0.009G on Y and .05G on Z.  Note in the final graph below, the magnitude continually drops over time. I have no idea why this is. It should always be 1 or very close to 1.

Two questions:

1. Is this a common or known phenomenon with accelerometers?
2. Could anyone recommend an accelerometer similar to the LIS3DSH where this undesirable behavior would not occur?

Thanks in advance for any information anyone might be able to provide.

[image: Accelerometer's X Reading]
[image: Accelerometer's Y Reading]
[image: Accelerometer's Z Reading]
[image: Accelerometer's Magnitude]

Comment: Is it following the temperature?  You are showing variation at thousandths of a g.  The datasheet gives values for temperature dependent stuff in that range.

Comment: Is it following the tides? (I admit that this may be an ignorant question.) Can you try mounting the sensors with different orientations with respect to vertical?

Comment: Do you have more than one unit? accelerometers do drift though but it should be bounded. the changes you measure are real small

Comment: For readers interested in this topic, the OP has posted the same question in the ST Community forum, so new comments or answers might appear over there: [Is accelerometer drift in the LIS3DSH normal behavior?](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BZHAfwSQH/is-accelerometer-drift-in-the-lis3dsh-normal-behavior)

Comment: The second question is a shopping question -- off-topic for this site. The offset errors on the X and Y axes are well within spec, especially given that this is a very low-cost device. But the scale-factor error on the Z axis seems excessive. Are you controlling for factors such as supply voltage, temperature, etc.? Are X and Y showing the same thing when you rotate the sensor so that they're vertical?

Comment: The Z axis change in particular seems rather excessive since that one is relatively insensitive to tilt. Have you tried cycling the power during the test?

Comment: The z axis has a different structure than the other two. it wouldnt be surprised if it does not perform as well. The z axis always seems to be a bit worse in the specs

Comment: @JRE - Regarding the temperature: This is in an indoor climate controlled environment.  I have not measured, but would be very surprised if the temperate is fluctuating more than 1 or 2 degrees C.  According to the datasheet, 2 degrees would be a .02% diff.  The diff I'm seeing in the Z axis is  5%.

Comment: @TerenceD sounds like you might want an electrolytic tilt sensor instead for such a static, sensitive application. more accurate and stable. more $$$ too

Comment: @DKNguyen - I'm looking through the data sheet trying to find information on the z-axis being worse than the x and y and not seeing anything.  Could you please explain more?

Comment: @DKNguyen Electrolytic tilt sensors are also *much* more complex to drive and mount (I did one in an application that could not tolerate long term drift a couple of years ago).

Comment: It is interesting to note that the typical applications are for relatively short time frames; the device contains factory calibration data that are loaded *each time the device is powered on*. Have you tried turning it off for a while and then turning it back on?

Comment: @Peter Smith - Yes, just tried power cycling the board and saw no change when powering it back on.  Example of some X,Y,Z values before: (-0.01129,-0.97998, 0.042847 ) and after: (-0.010376, -0.9801, 0.04187).

Comment: @TerenceD I was talking about a trend I have seen in accelerometer datasheets than the specific one you are using. Yours is also digital so that might be obfuscating certain things. For example, if you look at the ADXL335 datasheet, you can see the z-axis specs are different, and worse than the X and Y. This seems to be a common trend.

Comment: LIS3DSH provides temperature measurement of the internal circuit, can you please log that? The magnitude change of 0.05g is not negligible. Those sensors usually heat-up especially if you are reading at high sampling rate. for example, if you require one measurement every 5 minutes, it is good to turn off the internal circuit when not in use. Also, use the lowest sampling rate.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried testing multiple units and they all drift at the same rate, you might try using two of them (in similar temperature and pressure environments) to measure the difference in relative tilt between the object under test and some fixed reference point.